# Why is this happening to the milk?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, everyday-life

I noticed that when the Milk churn was leaking, and there was some milk on its outer surface, whenever I moved the churn, there was a residual extremely thin layer of milk under it, that started to slowly "bunch up" into thicker parts and disappear from between these thicker parts.

[image]

Please see the video.

My only suspicion is that first, because of the weight of the churn, the layer under it is extremely thin, much thinner then it would be without pressure. As the weight (churn) is removed from above it, the pressure is gone, and the Van der waals force tries to bunch the milk up into thicker parts, against gravity, until the two forces balance.

It is very important that this is happening fairly fast, in the matter of seconds, so it should not be caused by drying. The temperature is 72F and the surface is a plastic.

Question:

1. Why is this happening to the milk?

Answer (score 1):

It probably is a surface tension effect with the milk not wetting the plastic surface.

Creating surface requires the input of energy and the reverse is also true.

The milk starts off with a very large surface area and the surface tensional forces act so as to reduce the surface area of the milk.
In doing so the thickness (average height) of the milk increases which means that the milk has a greater gravitational potential energy than before and that energy comes from the energy "liberated" as the surface area of the milk decreases.

Comment: Thank you so much!